# Can 'display: -moz-box;' be used without over-riding 'margin 0 auto;'

Tags: css, firefox

I'm using the following CSS. In Chrome, IE and Safari the div is vertically centred on the screen, but in Firefox *'display: -moz-box;'* makes it align to the left.

If I turn of *'display: -moz-box;'*, the div centres, but then I lose the *'-moz-box-align: center;'* functionality.

**CSS**

```
    .myClass {
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 100%;
        width: 800px;

        /* Internet Explorer 10 */
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        -ms-flex-align: center;

        /* Firefox */
        display: -moz-box;
        -moz-box-align: center;

        /* Safari, Opera, and Chrome */
        display: -webkit-box;
        -webkit-box-align: center;

        /* W3C */
        display: box;
        box-align: center;
    }
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Any reason why you're using an extremely old and obsolete version of flexbox?

Comment: Nope, just something I read. I'm more than happy to use an equivalent.